# calling javascript from an embedded ruby tag

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

Easy one for Tuesday morning...
Im trying to call a javascript function from inside this ruby tag...

```
<% @efforts.each do |effort| %>
            <% if effort.project_task.project.project_name == "ADMIN"%>
            ??????????????
            <% else %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= effort.project_task.project.project_number %> <%= effort.project_task.project.project_name %> - 
                    <%= effort.project_task.task_name %>
                <td><%= text_field :effort, :hours, :name => 'effort_' + effort.project_task_id.to_s, :id => 'effort_' + effort.project_task_id.to_s,
                                   :value => "%d" % (effort.hours.nil? ? 0 : effort.hours), :size => 20 %>
                <td><%= link_to image_tag('icons/delete.png'), effort, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
            </tr>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
```

Where the question marks are i want to call a javascript function. But how do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [javascript_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper/javascript_tag):

```
<%= javascript_tag  do -%>
  alert('All is good')
<% end -%>
```